# displaying a selected icon from a nstableview in an imageviewer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, imageview, nstableview, nsfilemanager

I have a tableview that acts like an upload menu. It contains 4 columns : icon , name, size and date. Data are displayed in the nstablevier from an array controller (there is no IBOutlet tableview declared, and i don't use datasource). I have an image Viewer in the same window near the nstableview. When I select a row, I want to display the icon from the tableview in the imageViewer. but I can't find a solution. Can you help me and suggest a solution, a tutorial or documentation for example?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the interface builder bind the arraycontroller.selection.image to your imageViewer.value.

To do so click on the imageViewer, select the binding section on the right side of your interface builder window (7th icon) and in the "value" section click bind, set "bind to" to your Array Controller, Controllerkey is "selection", model key path is "image" or "icon"
(up to how you named it in your array controller).

Comment: thank you very much , but there still a "small" problem , when I insert an image view from the library in the window and run the app, an exception appears and sigabort

Comment: maybe you can upload your project anywhere so that i could look what went wrong?

Comment: sorry i can't, I don't have the right to do it . I hope you understand me well.
I dragged a NSimage Well in place of image view , it works but it displays the icon in a small sze. Butwhat I want , if I select a pdf file for example, it should show me the image in the image viewer of it :(

Comment: I just want a preview of the selected file in the tableview. Any Suggestion?

Comment: oh, seems like i misunderstood you, sorry for that you are trying to make it look like the previews in finder...

Comment: You might have a look at this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html        this is the way to do it on iOS, but the main function you are searching for is "Quick look".

Comment: thanks i will take a look , and if you you have a tutorial please send it to me thanks

Comment: I really don't know much about this, but you might google something like "xcode quicklook"